# What is the best or most efficient way to develop a GUI in C++?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I know that there are WYSIWYG editors available for GUI development, but are those the best way?

I know that in HTML if you use a WYSIWYG editor like Dreamweaver, what it produces will work but it will produce bad code that causes the program to not be as efficient as it could be.

Is it the same deal with C++ and other compiled languages?

Edit: I'll be developing for Windows 7. I probably wont be needing anything fancy like progress bars, just basic things like buttons, tick boxes, and a place to display output. It will just be running CMD commands based on what the user has selected before running it and displaying CMDs output in the program.

I guess the question I specifically wanted answered is whether it is best to "hand code" the GUI like you would in HTML, or if WYSIWYG editors are the way to go.

Comment: I like Qt5 with Visual Studio. Also this question is too broad for Stack Overflow, and will probably be closed.

Comment: The question is unanswerable... just consider how different the functionality required for a GUI like Photoshop, Gimp or OpenOffice is from say your average CD ripper or HTML form... each has their place.  You've given no hint of your actual requirements.

Comment: What OS are you developing for? To get that native and feel you need to write specific code, unfortunately. If you're willing to be less picky there are reasonably portable frameworks for this.

Comment: IUP looks promising. [IUP software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUP_(software))

Comment: If on Windows + VS, any Resource editor - included in paid version of VC++, or downloaded from software store- will do for your basic GUI functionality.